# How to create a “add tab“button in JAVAFX？

Tags: javafx, tabs, tabpanel

I want to create a button ,which will create a new tab to tabPane when clicking,and on the right of all tab alltime. I'll appreciate if there has any example how to do it.

Comment: assuming you want the "+" as f.i. in firefox tabs: not supported directly, you might try to either write your own TabPaneSkin or search for a 3rd party that supports it. Or hack around, add a tab with the plus as title and on selecting it the first time, fill its content and add another with the plus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should look similar to the code below.
This example uses a button above the TabPane.

```java
public class TabPaneSample extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

        VBox layout = new VBox(10); // VBox with spacing of 10. Button sits above TabPane
        layout.getChildren().addAll(newTabButton(tabPane), tabPane); // Adding button and TabPane to VBox

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    // Button that adds a new tab and selects it
    private Button newTabButton(TabPane tabPane) {
        Button addTab = new Button("Create Tab");
        addTab.setOnAction(event -> {
            tabPane.getTabs().add(new Tab("New Tab")); // Adding new tab at the end, so behind all the other tabs
            tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectLast(); // Selecting the last tab, which is the newly created one
        });
        return addTab;
    }
}
```

If you want it to be like in a browser, this code should do it. 
This uses the an empty tab at the end, which acts like a button. You can add an icon like + instead of the text in the tab label.

```java
public class TabPaneSample extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

        tabPane.getTabs().add(newTabButton(tabPane));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(tabPane));
        stage.show();
    }

    // Tab that acts as a button and adds a new tab and selects it
    private Tab newTabButton(TabPane tabPane) {
        Tab addTab = new Tab("Create Tab"); // You can replace the text with an icon
        addTab.setClosable(false);
        tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldTab, newTab) -> {
            if(newTab == addTab) {
                tabPane.getTabs().add(tabPane.getTabs().size() - 1, new Tab("New Tab")); // Adding new tab before the "button" tab
                tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(tabPane.getTabs().size() - 2); // Selecting the tab before the button, which is the newly created one
            }
        });
        return addTab;
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm .. I suspect that's not what the OP wants - the requirement seems to be more like the "+" in f.i. firefox tabs ..

Comment: Ok, I added this option now.

Comment: This works for me.  Except when I added the first tab, the listener would add a blank tab.  I added 'if (2 > tabPane.getTabs().size()) return;' inside the listener so it would not do that.